# Increase returned number/pages on pagination

Tags: php, pagination

Im trying to increase the numbers/Pages for my pagination. I have 64 pages set, and this is how it shows now: « Previous 1 2 3 4 … 64 Next ». How do I control so I can show more numbers? In my case i need the counter to go up to about 30.

My query:

```
if ( $pagination === 'numbered' ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
        $output .= '<div class="nav-links2">';

        $output .= paginate_links( array(
            'base'      => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format'    => '?paged=%#%',
            'current'   => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total'     => $wp_query->max_num_pages

        ) );
        $output .= '</div>';  
        return $output;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the Codex page for [`paginate_links`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) for all accepted arguments.

The two you want to modify are `mid_size` and possibly `end_size`.

```
$output .= paginate_links( array(
    'base'      => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format'    => '?paged=%#%',
    'current'   => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total'     => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'mid_size'  => 8 // number of page links to display on either side of current page

) );
```